# Final release date for the next major Code First Entity Framework version after 4.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have developed a project using MVC3 and Code first Entity Framework 4.0 as data access layer. But when hosting the project on GoDaddy.com, CF Entity Framework throws security exception error as it requires "Full Trust" level for execution which is not provided by most of the web hosting providers.

I have searched various blogs for a workaround and found that ADO.Net team is aware of the bug and it will get fixed in the next release.

Does any one know the **dates for the next release** so that I can take a call on whether I need to throw away Model created based on CF entity framework and used ADO.Net Entity framework.

Comment: Only MS has idea when final version will be release. Last information was Q1 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official [announcement is here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/02/ef-4-1-is-coming-dbcontext-api-amp-code-first-rtw.aspx). It will be called Entity Framework 4.1. RC is planned for second half of March and RTW one month later.

Answer (score 1):

There has been any official release dates announced yet but it is quite possible it will be part of the next version of the framework .NET 5.0 vNext and Visual Studio.

Comment: That's too bad. Mirosoft guys should provide a fix since it is causing problems to most of the developers that are using Code first entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read in the official forums, it's some time this year.